# VBA Sorting Blank Cells to Bottom

Tags: vba, sorting, blank-line

I want to remowe some duplicate Value from an excel Column, but before that I need to sort it right so it dont Remowe any contatn i want to have. The problem i got are the blank cells, i want them to be remowed but they keep staying at any sorting on the top. Here is my sorting code, any Idea?

```
ABC.Range("A1", "AF" & lngLastRow).Sort key1:=ABC.Range("A1:A" & lngLastRow), _
   order1:=xlDescending, key2:=ABC.Range("P1:P" & lngLastRow), _
   order2:=xlDescending, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
```

I need a Solution where I can sort them (Blanks) to the bottom with the second key. I DON'T need a solution where i delete them because some of the duplicates have only blank values in this column and I still need to keep them if they dont have any alternativ.

Comment: You are working with one column or you sort whole table based on specific column?

Comment: I sort a whole tabel based by this 2 collumns, first Descending by column A then as second source i took colummn P where I want if it is possible to keep only the P-s with some text up, so when I Remowe the duplicats only the one with text in P wont be deleted

Comment: And blanks are located only in one column, right? And you want to only move them to bottom?

Comment: Yes,  there are blanks in some other Columns but I only want to sort this Column so the blanks are at the bottom in the second sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it: check if we have blank in specified column, if so, move entire row to the bottom and delete it (so entire table moves up one row). Repeat until there's non-empty cell at the top in specified column.

```
Sub MoveBlanksToBottom()
'you have to specify size of your table here
Dim rows, columns, columnsWithBlanks As Long
rows = 10
columns = 4
columnWithBlanks = 1
'we will loop until the first row in specified column will be non empty
Do While IsEmpty(Cells(1, columnWithBlanks))
    'copy entire row to the bottom
    For i = 1 To columns
        Cells(rows + 1, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Value
    Next
    'delete the row
    Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Loop

End Sub
```

You should use this `Sub` after you sorted your table.

You can pass size of a table as parameters to make it more flexible:

```
Sub MoveBlanksToBottom()
'you have to specify size of your table here
Dim rows, columns, columnsWithBlanks As Long
rows = 10
columns = 4
columnWithBlanks = 1
```

should be replaced by

```
Sub MoveBlanksToBottom(rows As Long, columns As Long, columnsWithBlanks As Long)
```

Then you can call it like this: `Call MoveBlanksToBottom(10, 4, 1)`.

Comment: I could also make a much easier solution like I add another Column that have values 1 and 0 for non empty and empty, but isnt there any option that just keeps the blanks in bottom by the second sorting I mean common there must be some comand in VBA is not that big deal or is it?

Comment: I don't think so, it's how sorting works, keeps blanks first (no value is before any value). You could order it descending instead of ascending (this would keep blanks at the bottom, but I think that's not what you need). You need some workaround like one I posted.

Comment: That dont do it, however i sort it it keeps the blanks up Ascending or Descending like the sorting dont works

Comment: I just tried it wit athin a "zzz" value and I think the second sorting just dont work for some reasson but i dont know why

Comment: It works perfectly... How should it work according to you? Becuase, this sorting works like that: first, it sorts accordingly to column in `key1`, if in this sorting, there are ties, the `key2` column would resolve them. For example, these are 4 rows: (2,1), (1,1), (1,0), (2, 0). After sorting it ascending, first column would become: 1, 1, 2, 2 (we have 2 ties). Then, second sorting will sort these rows in this order: (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 1).

Answer (score 0):

This option should sort the blank cells:
DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

Answer (score -1):

this deals with deleting the blank cells. Change the sheet name and column parameters as required:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long

n = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To n
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
            .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: I dont want to delet them i want them on the bottom in the second key, because i also need some of the blanks